# Why is it that inner join tables in mysql returns a zero if a field is null and does not display rows with null fields in an HTML table?

Tags: mysql

I am just curious why inner join tables returns a zero value with a data type of INT. It is not even included in the HTML table if I display the results of the query. Not like an outer join it displays all the rows and left the empty fields blank.

Comment: Could you share the query you ran, the results you got, and the results you expected to get?

Comment: A SQL query is going to return the data that it finds.  It doesn't manipulate that data unless you tell it to.  And what does that have to do with HTML?  It seems like there's a lot of context here you haven't bothered to share.

Comment: I am using html tables to view the results of the query. And I am just curious anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your INT columns are returning 0 from a query with an INNER JOIN that have no matching results the NULL that is actually being returned most likely got converted to 0 in between your DAL and your front-end.

Your question is not very clear, though.

Comment: That's great. This helped but it was also my mistake I just have a predefined value (value==0)  from my inputs. Thanks anyways. @RIan Gillis